How to replace certain elements in a list with new elements in R
I have an existing list as follows,
a <- list(~X11 + O1, ~X11 + X21 + O2 + O1 + C1 + X11*C1)

I want to replace X11 with B1 and replace X21 with B2 so that the new list a_new should look like
a_new <- list(~B1 + O1, ~B1 + B2 + O2 + O1 + C1 + B1*C1)

Is there a way to achieve this in R?
A second question is that sometimes X11 can be X12, X13, … and X21 can be X22, X23… So the former case will be replaced with B1 and the latter will be replaced with B2. Is it possible to first identify if the original list a contains any elements that belong to a given list b, say,
b <- list(~X11 + X12 + X13, ~X21 + X22 + X23)

and replace the elements in a that belong to list b with B1 and B2 accordingly? In the example, since X11 belongs to X11, X12 and X13, so X11 is replaced with B1 and the same applies to X21 which is replaced with B2. This check step is necessary prior to substituting the elements.

Have a look at substitute().

I think what you really need is to compose formulas. You could try as.formula().

Can you give me an example of how to implement substitute() in my case? Thank you!

You can do:
subs <- alist(X11 = B1,
              X21 = B2)

lapply(a, \(x) do.call(substitute,  list(x, subs)))

[[1]]
~B1 + O1

[[2]]
~B1 + B2 + O2 + O1 + C1 + B1 * C1

In response to your edit, this is how you might generalize this approach if I've understood you correctly.
a <- list(~X11 + O1, ~X11 + X21 + O2 + O1 + C1 + X11*C1)
b <- list(~X11 + X12 + X13, ~X21 + X22 + X23)

f <- \(nms, replacement) {
  replacement <- paste0(replacement, seq_along(nms))
  Map(\(nms, replacement) {
    vars <- all.vars(nms)
    setNames(lapply(rep(replacement, length(vars)), as.name), vars)
  }, nms, replacement) |>
    unlist()
}

Where f() returns a named list of symbols to use in substitute()
lapply(a, \(x) do.call(substitute, list(x, f(b, "B")))) 

[[1]]
~B1 + O1

[[2]]
~B1 + B2 + O2 + O1 + C1 + B1 * C1


Thank you! I posed additional question in the original post. Can you help me with that as well?

@Phoebe - I've tried to answer your new question but if it's not what you're after it would be better to revise this question back to just the original and ask your follow up as a new question where you can better explain it.

Hi Iroha, thanks for your answers. That is the answer I'm looking for actually that can first identify the elements to be replaced and then do the replacement with new elements. However, I don't quite understand the f function as it does not look like an R function. What does Map() mean and what is (...)?

Map() is just a wrapper for mapply(simplify = FALSE).  The ... means that it's a variadic function, e.g. that it takes any number of arguments.
